# Copy and paste a cell so that the data does not change after a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

I want to stop a vlookup from working after it has filled the appropriate cell with data.

Column B will contain stock figures from a material that is typed into column A.

The stock will be constantly changing.

Once a cell has been filled with data from a vlookup I want it to stay that way.

I do not want it to refresh as the stock figures refresh as they were the figures relevant at that time.

Comment: Have you tried `paste values` under paste options?

Comment: Hi, yes this does work but as other people will be using this I was looking to create some form of macro button.

Comment: Within VBA you could try `Range($B$1).Value = Range($B$1$).Value` (*Untested*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within VBA, as @Steven Pomponio mentioned, you may set the value equal to what the value already is. That means that if a formula has been calculated and returned a result (or error for that matter), the result replaces the formula in the given cell.

```
Sub SetValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      
    With ws
        fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    ws.Range("B1:B" & fRow).Value = ws.Range("B1:B" & fRow).Value

End Sub
```

I would assign this to a `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`-event or a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`-event.

Above code will also take into account the amount of rows you have in your B-column.

Comment: Hi, this seems to only work for row 1. I have tried amending the range and giving it a full value and also tried changing the row count and I have now given myself a VB error.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me? Of course, you might need to change the column of where the fRow looks - right now, it looks at column B (2). You may need to adjust some values/ranges in the code, but this works perfectly at my machine.

Comment: Hi, yes I have changed cell references and my sheet name. I am going to delete it all and re enter. Thank you.